# awk command to print only part of matching lines

Tags: awk

awk command to compare lines in file and print only first line if there are some new words in other lines.

For example: file.txt is having

```
i am going
i am going today
i am going with my friend
```

output should be

```
I am going
```

Comment: What about if there is one more line `i am going today oh boy`. Since line 2 contains all of those words, should it be printed. What about if there are two more lines `hi mom` and `i am here mom hi` would `hi mom` count? Perhaps more sample lines and your expected results would be helpful to clarify.

Comment: intention is to compare only first few words

Comment: Do you mean something like this? cat file.txt | awk  '{print $1,$2,$3}'

Comment: That would output all three records @aicastell and the `cat` is superfluous as `awk '{print $1,$2,$3}' file.txt` would work here.

Comment: @Abhinash I have this feelnig though that you actual file is a lot more complicated. Are these records being compared always sorted like this. What if there is an unrelated record in between your sample records 1 and 2 like `some random record` would it still output `I am going`. We could write some code to do exactly what you want based on your small sample data, but I have a feeling there will be 100 "But what if` follow up questions as your real data comes to light.

Comment: @Abhinash please add some more examples to make your question clearer.. also, you've to add what you've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work for the sample input but perhaps will fail for the actual one, unless you have a representative input we wouldn't know...

```
$ awk 'NR>1 && $0~p {if(!f) print p; f=1; next} {p=$0; f=0}' file 
i am going
```

you may want play with `p=$0` to restrict matching number of fields if the line lengths are not in increasing order...